# Why $w'_x(\delta) \leq w_x(2\delta)$?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, weak-convergence

In the book by Billingsley *Convergence of Probability Measures* at page number 123.

Author stated that
$$w'_x(\delta) \leq w_x(2\delta), \ \delta < 1/2.$$

and

$$w_x(\delta) \leq 2w_x(\delta) + j(x)$$

Why this is so? I actually can't visualise the picture of it.

Glimpse of that page:
[image: Image of the part where I stuck]